# User behavior inside my web page

Tags: analytics

Does anybody know if there is a way to understand what users are doing on my web page? I can see overall stats with Google Analytics but I can't really understand what users are looking at, if they are reading my content, etc.

Does anybody know if there is a free or paid service that I could use?

Dani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using one of the analytics things that does heatmaps.

These give a visual representation of where people are clicking on the site, and I think some may let you track where the cursor is as well.

This is about as close as you can get to what you want - there's no way to track what someone's eyes are looking at,

Wikipedia claims that google analytics can do this. I've not seen it in analytics, but it may well be hiding there somewhere. I have used clicktale a bit before though:

http://www.clicktale.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try [Mouseflow](http://mouseflow.com/). You can even record your visitors and watch the videos. Haven't tried it but looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

The Site Overlay report in Google Analytics is probably what Wikipedia is referring to. However, it doesn't work most of the time (it's a "piece of crap" in Google's own words).

ClickTale is okay. I recommend CrazyEgg: http://crazyegg.com/